# Is there a function to infer text from Word2Vec vector

Tags: python-3.x, word2vec

I was wondering if say I used a pretrained model, if I would be able to infer a word from a Word2Vec vector obtained from a text I am trying to analyze. Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your input is, and what you'd expect/hope the output to be? (You can certainly look up the word-vectors for words in your text. And you could find other words that have vectors close to those vectors, or an average of some or all of those vectors. But it'd not clear what you mean by 'infer' here.)

Comment: I’m trying to apply Word2Vec to cryptanalysis. I would calculate a Word2Vec vector with for each supposed word in cipher text, and try to infer what the word would be from the Word2Vec vector. I would use the model trained with the google dataset.

Comment: So what's your input... fragments-of-ciphertext-that-might-be-words? No competent encryption would let you detect word-boundaries or repeating words. And what's your hoped-for output... semantic vectors for fragments-of-ciphertext? Because no competent cipher would let you see word-boundaries or a even a strong hint that a word has repeated, it's unlikely those can be trained. And reusing existing word-vectors, like the GoogleNews set, isn't much help if your input is only ciphertext. (This would only have some hope in some sort of simple folk/substitution 'encryption'.)

Comment: Thank you man. I'm trying to solve the z340 cipher from the zodiac killer who we suspect might be using a column transposition combined with a homophonic substitution. But I think you're right, any ciphertext won't let me detect word-boundaries. But say if I was able to obtain the word-boundaries. Could I calculate the word2vec vector for this fragment of ciphertext and obtain a semantic ouput vector?

Comment: If the cipher was so simple that word-like tokens with stable meanings repeat in sentence-like contexts, and there was lots of data showing repeat uses of each word-like-token in many subtly-varied contexts, then yes, you could train word-vectors on that data. But few ciphers are like that, and training word-vectors requires a lot of data. Only if a cipher had already been easily broken by traditional cryptanalysis, would I suspect it was regular enough, and with enough example ciphertext, to be amenable to Word2Vec methods.